# I am not able to fetch songs from my SD card using this coding.Can I do this way or I need to do it by Content Provider

Tags: android, media-player, avaudioplayer

This is the code:

```
public class Songs {  
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/Internal SD card/");
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();  
private Context mContext;  

public Songs(Context context){
    mContext=context;
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){  
    File home = mContext.getDir("Music", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);;//new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {  
       for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
 // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Add some more information what you are trying to do, what the problem is and what you have already tried. The title is not really the place to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take permission in Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes Pratyesh I have added for both Read and write(External Storage).

Answer (score 0):

By running

```
File home = mContext.getDir("Music", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

you get a path to a directory private to your application (e.g. /data/data/your.package.name/app_Music). If it doesn't exist, it will be created. If you want to get your music from some specific directory on your sd card, you can use something like:

```
File home = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "path/to/your/dir");
```